# How to pass Git Token credentials in Groovy stage running on Docker image via Jenkins job

Tags: git, jenkins, github, groovy, jenkins-groovy

I have created Jenkins Pipeline to migrate Git Repos to AWS Code Commit.
This Jenkins job pulls a Docker Image and then runs code written in Jenkins Stages.

In one of the stage I am executing a Shell Script as below :
In this stage, I am intending to clone Git Repo in the docker container with mirror option and the commit the code to remote aws-codecommit repository. I have login details stored in Credentials store of Jenkins

However it fails with error : **fatal: unable to access 'https://mygitserver:myorg/myrepo.git/': Port number ended with 'i**'.
I believe this docker image is unable to read credentials but not sure how to fix this
PS : repos.txt have all repo-names

```
stage('Migrate Repos') {
                withCredentials([string(credentialsId: 'onprem-gitbuild-token', variable: 'TOKEN')]) {
                    
                    sh '''
                    while read r; do
                    echo $r
                    aws codecommit create-repository --repository-name $r --region us-west-2 
                    git clone --mirror https://mygitserver:myorg/myrepos.git 
                    cd $r.git
                    git push ssh://git-codecommit.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/v1/repos/$r --all
                    git push ssh://git-codecommit.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/v1/repos/$r --tags
                    sleep 10
                    aws codecommit update-default-branch --repository-name $r --default-branch-name master --region us-west-2
                    cd ../
                    done < repos.txt

                    '''
```

Comment: hi, interesting, perhaps change the url - `https://mygitserver:myorg` - the colon goes in front of a port number, but there is a string there.

Comment: Sorry ya I had mistakenly put : before org .  I have corrected that but still issues with it.                         
          



 git clone --mirror https://****@myreposerver.com/myorg/myrepo.git
Cloning into bare repository '@myreposerver.com/myorg/myrepo.git'...
fatal: unable to access 'https://mytokenrandomc2f3sds131f93443434343443906d94fce577ecaf3935970/': Could not resolve host: mytokenrandomc2f3sds131f93443434343443906d94fce577ecaf3935970